# App won't run on device!

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod-touch

The app I'm currently developing works perfectly on the simulator.

However, plugging in an ipod touch and clicking "run" won't run it on device.

There are no error messages or anything - it builds the project, and then says "finished running ...". Nothing comes up on the device.

If it helps, I'm using the Core Plot charting library, other projects seem to build and run on device properly. Its just odd there are no errors.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try performing clean and build ? if it's not working add core plot references again and see.

Comment: Added the core plot references again. Don't know what I did differently this time, but it works, thank you.

Comment: @Thomas Clayson I have faced this problem before that's why I asked you to add core-plot again.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you get this error if the provisional profile is expired. Please verify the provisional profile in the device and in the xcode organizer.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you something on the console. Look at the console.

Comment: its not telling me anything on the console unfortunately.

Comment: It's got to be saying SOMETHING on the console.

Comment: same problem, not using core plot, and no, there is NOTHING on the console :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636924/xcode-succeeds-build-but-does-not-copy-to-ios-device-and-terminates-debugger-i solved it

Answer (score 1):

Add `NSLog(@"001");` and `NSLog(002);` ... calls to your code to check where the app stops.